# Decrease a variable until a number is reached zero

Tags: functions, operations-research, programming

I have a while loop in a programming language. I am looking for an elegant way to subtract an intial value by one until the new value reachs zero, until zero the substrations return always zero.

I am using module operation but I have some problem to get the right solution
For example:

```
// R project language
s = 5
for(i in 1:10) {
    s = s - ((s) %% (s-1))
    print(s)
}
[1] 4
[1] 3
[1] 2
[1] 2
[1] 2
[1] 2
[1] 2
[1] 2
[1] 2
[1] 2
```

what I wish is:

```
[1] 4
[1] 3
[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// R project language
s = 5
for(i in 1:10) {
    if (s > 0) { s = s - 1 }
    print(s)
}
```

Comment: Thanks I find right now also this solution: f = f - 1, print(max(0,f))

Answer (score 1):

If your programming language has ternary operators, consider:

$$s = s-((s==0)?0:1).$$

Or maybe

$$s = s-\max(s, 0)$$

But really you should probably just use an if statement to verify that the value is not $0$ before subtracting.